# Probability Density Function of a Minimum Function

Tags: probability

Suppose $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_5$ are independent $\operatorname{unif}(0,1)$ random variables.
Suppose $T = \min(U_1, U_2, \dots, U_5)$.

How would I find the p.d.f. of $T$? I know how to do regular cases like $T = A + B$ given the distribution of $A$ and $B$ but how do I deal with a minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find the cumulative distribution function $F_T(t)$ of $T$. Given any number $t$, we need to find $\Pr(T\le t)$.  It is easier to find first $\Pr(T\gt t)$.

The minimum of the $U_i$ is $\gt t$ precisely if **all** the $U_i$ are greater than $t$.

For $0\le t\le 1$, we have $\Pr(U_i\gt t)=1-t$.

So the probability **all** the $U_i$ are $\gt t$ is, by independence, $(1-t)^5$.

It follows that
$$\Pr(T\le t)=F_T(t)=1-(1-t)^5,$$
for all $t$ between $0$ and $1$. For the probability density function $f_T(t)$, differentiate $F_T(t)$.

**Remark:** The same basic idea can be used to find the distribution of the  minimum of $n$ independent random variables with continuous distribution. A  simpler variant deals with the distribution of the maximum.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still a little bit confused in regards to the first sentence. Why is the minimum $> t$?

Comment: I am trying to find the cdf of $T$, that is, the probability that $T\le t$. We find first the probability that $T\gt t$. The smallest is $\gt t$ if and only if they are all $\gt t$. Will add a couple of introductory lines to answer so it can be followed by others who read it  later.